# Php simple email with HTML.....how to display the php values

Tags: php, html

Sorry for such a noob question but I've searched everywhere and found little help.  I have a mysql database sending a simple receipt written in html.  Upon request the php file should load data from mysql, the html sends fine but running into trouble displaying the php looked up information inside the html:

```
<?php
$data2 = "12/12/14";
$message = 
'<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Language content=en-us>

<meta name=ProgId content=FrontPage.Editor.Document>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=text/html; charset=windows-1252>
<title>DRAFT</title>
</head>

<body leftmargin=50>








<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=808 height=115>
<!-- MSTableType=layout -->
<tr>
    <td align=center width=206>
    <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0 width=100% height=100%>
        <!-- MSCellFormattingTableID=4 -->
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor=#000000 colspan=2 height=1>
            <img alt= width=1 height=1 src=MsSpacer.gif></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor=#000000 width=1>
            <img alt= width=1 height=1 src=MsSpacer.gif></td>
            <td align=center valign=middle height=100% width=100%>
            <!-- MSCellFormattingType=content -->
            <b>****</b><br>
            101 SomeStreet Rd.<br>
            City, State, Zip<br>
            Office: ****<br>
            Fax: ****<br>
       &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    <td valign=top width=275 height=115>
    <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0 width=100% height=100%>
        <!-- MSCellFormattingTableID=3 -->
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor=#000000 height=1>
            <img alt= width=1 height=1 src=MsSpacer.gif></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign=top height=100% width=100%>
            <!-- MSCellFormattingType=content -->
            &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    <td valign=top height=115 width=327>
    <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0 width=100% height=100%>
        <!-- MSCellFormattingTableID=2 -->
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor=#000000 colspan=2 height=1>
            <img alt= width=1 height=1 src=MsSpacer.gif></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign=top width=100%>
            <!-- MSCellFormattingType=content -->
            Date <u><?php echo $data2; ?></u><br>
            Year ___<u>%year%</u>__ Mileage __<u>%mileage%</u>__<br>
            Make __<u>%make%</u>__ Model __<u>%model%</u>__<br>
            Vin# __<u>%VIN%</u>__<br>
            Color __<u>%color%</u>__ Trim: __<u>%trim%</u>_____</td>
            <td bgcolor=#000000 height=100% width=1>
            <img alt= width=1 height=1 src=MsSpacer.gif></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=808 height=263>
<!-- MSTableType=layout -->
<tr>
    <td valign=top bordercolordark=#000000 bordercolor=#000000 height=184>
    <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0 width=100% height=100%>
        <!-- MSCellFormattingTableID=1 -->
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor=#000000 colspan=3 height=1>
            <img alt= width=1 height=1 src=MsSpacer.gif></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor=#000000 width=1>
            <img alt= width=1 height=1 src=MsSpacer.gif></td>
            <td valign=top bordercolordark=#000000 bordercolor=#000000 width=100%>
            <!-- MSCellFormattingType=content -->
            <b>&nbsp; PAY TO THE <br>
 &nbsp; ORDER OF</b> 
            ___<u>%dealername%</u>______<u>%soldprice%</u>___<br>
            <br>

            __<u>%num2word%</u>__;
                                                                                                        <b>DOLLARS</b><p><font size=2>&nbsp;<br>
&nbsp; *****/OWNER<br>
&nbsp; OFFICE:******; SIGNATURE</font></td>
            <td bgcolor=#000000 height=100% width=1>
            <img alt= width=1 height=1 src=MsSpacer.gif></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor=#000000 colspan=3 height=1>
            <img alt= width=1 height=1 src=MsSpacer.gif></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height=79 width=808>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>








</body>

</html>';
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";


mail($BidEmail, " test", $message, $headers);

 ?>
```

Comment: and this isn't working ... how?

Comment: Please post the code which places this HTML into an email message body and sends it. More context is needed, because given _only_ what you posted, it would work to place `$data2` into that string.  But if you are building this into the string body of an HTML message, `echo` is probably not what you need.

Comment: it displays nothing at all where the date should be and if I try '$data2' it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Are you closing the original `<?php` tag somewhere?

Comment: that just displays   echo $data2;

Comment: You have this all encased in single quotes. Single quotes don't parse the contents. Change the single quotes to double quotes or a heredoc, and remove `<?php echo` and `; ?>`.

Comment: your HTML isn't HTML, attributes values must have quotes.

Comment: @Jasen I believe you're thinking of XHTML. HTML allows unquoted attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code with :

```
$message = 
"<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Language content=en-us>

<meta name=ProgId content=FrontPage.Editor.Document>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=text/html; charset=windows-1252>
<title>DRAFT</title>
</head>

<body leftmargin=50>








<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=808 height=115>
<!-- MSTableType=layout -->
<tr>
    <td align=center width=206>
    <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0 width=100% height=100%>
        <!-- MSCellFormattingTableID=4 -->
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor=#000000 colspan=2 height=1>
            <img alt= width=1 height=1 src=MsSpacer.gif></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor=#000000 width=1>
            <img alt= width=1 height=1 src=MsSpacer.gif></td>
            <td align=center valign=middle height=100% width=100%>
            <!-- MSCellFormattingType=content -->
            <b>****</b><br>
            101 SomeStreet Rd.<br>
            City, State, Zip<br>
            Office: ****<br>
            Fax: ****<br>
       &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    <td valign=top width=275 height=115>
    <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0 width=100% height=100%>
        <!-- MSCellFormattingTableID=3 -->
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor=#000000 height=1>
            <img alt= width=1 height=1 src=MsSpacer.gif></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign=top height=100% width=100%>
            <!-- MSCellFormattingType=content -->
            &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    <td valign=top height=115 width=327>
    <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0 width=100% height=100%>
        <!-- MSCellFormattingTableID=2 -->
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor=#000000 colspan=2 height=1>
            <img alt= width=1 height=1 src=MsSpacer.gif></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign=top width=100%>
            <!-- MSCellFormattingType=content -->
            Date <u>$data2</u><br>
            Year ___<u>%year%</u>__ Mileage __<u>%mileage%</u>__<br>
            Make __<u>%make%</u>__ Model __<u>%model%</u>__<br>
            Vin# __<u>%VIN%</u>__<br>
            Color __<u>%color%</u>__ Trim: __<u>%trim%</u>_____</td>
            <td bgcolor=#000000 height=100% width=1>
            <img alt= width=1 height=1 src=MsSpacer.gif></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=808 height=263>
<!-- MSTableType=layout -->
<tr>
    <td valign=top bordercolordark=#000000 bordercolor=#000000 height=184>
    <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0 width=100% height=100%>
        <!-- MSCellFormattingTableID=1 -->
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor=#000000 colspan=3 height=1>
            <img alt= width=1 height=1 src=MsSpacer.gif></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor=#000000 width=1>
            <img alt= width=1 height=1 src=MsSpacer.gif></td>
            <td valign=top bordercolordark=#000000 bordercolor=#000000 width=100%>
            <!-- MSCellFormattingType=content -->
            <b>&nbsp; PAY TO THE <br>
 &nbsp; ORDER OF</b> 
            ___<u>%dealername%</u>______<u>%soldprice%</u>___<br>
            <br>

            __<u>%num2word%</u>__;
                                                                                                        <b>DOLLARS</b><p><font size=2>&nbsp;<br>
&nbsp; *****/OWNER<br>
&nbsp; OFFICE:******; SIGNATURE</font></td>
            <td bgcolor=#000000 height=100% width=1>
            <img alt= width=1 height=1 src=MsSpacer.gif></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor=#000000 colspan=3 height=1>
            <img alt= width=1 height=1 src=MsSpacer.gif></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height=79 width=808>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>








</body>

</html>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
Date <u><?php echo $data2; ?></u><br>
```

to:

```
Date <u>'. $data2 . '</u><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not good way you define a $message like that with many special character and php variable in it.

User below way to define variable with variable or long text:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Also the best way you define that message is in a html file and then get the html using function

$message = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/abc.html")

In this way it is very easy to separate email message part with email send function.

If you really want like your way:

$message = "the first part of your message"  .  $data .  "second part of your message" .

Hope this help to you.

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit unclear but I think where you have `%something%` you should instead join the values in

```
'html content '.htmlspecialchars($something).' more html content'
```